# Запятая в ССП с общим членом(?)

Tags: запятые

Правда, для него ситуация рисуется не одним цветом(,) и он завершает свой рассказ.
Нужна ли запятая в скобках? Или ПРАВДА - общий член (не знаю как назвать) для двух предложений?
По следующему предложению похожий вопрос (внутри немного сократил):
Несмотря на то, что собственно о России как государстве можно говорить со второй половины XVI в., многие  институты и механизмы, которые были характерны для него в тот период, получили оформление в гораздо более ранние времена, складываясь в рамках таких политических образований, как Хазарский каганат, Волжская Булгария(,) и позже были унаследованы одним из осколков Золотой Орды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правда, для него ситуация рисуется не одним цветом, и он завершает свой рассказ.

Вводное слово не общее, относится к первому предложению.

Несмотря на то что собственно о России как государстве можно говорить со второй половины XVI в., многие институты и механизмы, которые были характерны для него в тот период, получили оформление в гораздо более ранние времена, складываясь в рамках таких политических образований, как Хазарский каганат, Волжская Булгария, и позже были унаследованы одним из осколков Золотой Орды.

Запятая закрывает деепричастный и сравнительный оборот, поэтому ставится.

Основа:  многие институты и механизмы получили оформление и  были унаследованы.